# Handling live JSON Feeds

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

so I set up Firebase in my android project and added the receivers to respond to any push notifications. When I use the firebase notifications console and send it to the device and I have the app running I see the receiver getting hit and I am able to take action. Let's say I have a live feed that gets updated every 2 or 3 seconds. I setup firebase server side components to send an HTTP post request and firebase sends a notification to the device. However, I noticed that my device isn't receiving all notifications. I considered using ACK architecture but I am wondering if firebase is reliable in delivering these push notifications 100 % of the time

Comment: post receivers code here.

Comment: You want to create your own notification even if app is in background ?

Comment: i want to understand how an app can receive a firebase push notification if its not at all running and it goes to the notification tray. If the app was backgrounded the receivers will still get the notifications. In the firebase console it is saying the delivery was completed even though i dont see any notification on my device

Comment: Include your FirebaseMessagingService code considering there are many probabilities.